# Source for high resolution satellite images

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite, india

I am looking for high resolution imagery of the Nicobar Islands.
Ideally 3 images (2004, 2005 and 2014/15).
My budget is 1500 USD.
Which image providers would you advice?
Until now I have only worked with free (Landsat) imagery therefore I do not know where to ask.

Comment: What kind of data do you require? Pancromatic?

Comment: No multiple bands (just like landsat). Purpose is vegetation mapping

Comment: Are you analysing these images as part of a research work? In that case you might be eligible for a [DigitalGlobe Image Grant](http://www.digitalglobefoundation.org/application-process).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to acquire about 2000 square kilometers (based on a quick estimate on google earth) of imagery, at three points in time, for 1500$.
That means, you're looking for data at a price of 0.25$ per square kilometer. Three of the major data providers (DigitalGlobe, Airbus & Blackbridge) all have their lowest price points significantly above that.
You could look into the Indian Remote Sensing (IRS) series, which provides reasonable data at a low price. You can find more information about the IRS series at [this site](http://bhuvan.nrsc.gov.in/bhuvan/content/indian-remote-sensing-satellites-earth-observation-india-high-resolution-satellite-data). However, I am uncertain if their data is available at the price point that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do not need the whole reagion at once but rather certain sites within the Islands. Exactly the east coast of great Nicobar, south coast of Car Nicobar and the islands of Trinket, Katchall and Nancowry complete.